# How to make a condition in CSS with an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a condition in CSS. To do that I have to access to an HTML attribute and, depending on its value, show True or False, but I don't know how to do it.

```
<div class="block">
      <div class="question">
      Question
      </div>
      <div class="answer" data-value="true">
      </div>
</div>
```

The CSS file works fine when I write

```
.answer:after {
content: "OK";
}
```

But when I try to access to the attribute "data-value" with a CSS selector, the content specified it's not shown:

```
.answer:after[data-value="true"] {
content: "True";
}

.answer:after[data-value="false"] {
content: "False"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution of applying CSS using Data-Attribute.

```css
.answer:after {
content: "OK";
}

.answer[data-value="true"]:after {
content: "True";
}

.answer[data-value="false"]:after {
content: "False"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
      <div class="question">
      Question
      </div>
      <div class="answer" data-value="true">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `[data-value="true"]` before `:after`. The way you have it now is looking for that attribute on `:after` instead of `.answer`

```
.answer[data-value="true"]:after {
  content:"True";
}
.answer[data-value="false"]:after {
  content:"False";
}
```